# Converting a JPEG image to a byte array - COM exception

Tags: c#, wpf, image, com, file-io

Using C#, I'm trying to load a JPEG file from disk and convert it to a byte array. So far, I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame bitmapFrame;

    using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Lenna.jpg", FileMode.Open))
    {
        bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
    }

    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder encoder = 
        new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);

    byte[] myBytes;
    using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(memoryStream); // Line ARGH

        // mission accomplished if myBytes is populated
        myBytes = memoryStream.ToArray(); 
    }
}
```

However, executing line `ARGH` gives me the message:

> COMException was unhandled. The handle is invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

I don't think there is anything special about the file `Lenna.jpg` - I downloaded it from http://computervision.wikia.com/wiki/File:Lenna.jpg. Can you tell what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Check the examples from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx

Also it's better to use classes from `System.Drawing`

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Lenna.jpg");
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    arr =  ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: How could i do the same if i did not know he exact type of the image file?i mean would it be JPEG or GIF how coudl i save both files?

Comment: This is helpful, but the `img.Save()` call should be taking `img.RawFormat` as the second argument instead of `ImageFormat.Jpeg`. The code above works, but this should help anyone working with other formats.

Answer (score 29):

Other suggestion:

```
byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes ( Server.MapPath ( "noimage.png" ) );
```

Should be working not only with images.

Answer (score 5):

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)  
{   
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();     

 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);   
 return  ms.ToArray();   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason this error happens is because the BitmapFrame.Create() method you are using defaults to an OnDemand load. The BitmapFrame doesn't try to read the stream it's associated with until the call to encoder.Save, by which point the stream is already disposed.

You could either wrap the entire function in the using {} block, or use an alternative BitmapFrame.Create(), such as:

```
BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```