# Image comparison by comparing pixel

Tags: c#, arrays, image, image-processing, system.drawing

I have two same image which are taken different resolution screen .so I have written a code in C# which makes images to have same size

*Dimension : 320x224

Horizontal resolution :96dpi.

Vertical resolution:96dpi.

Bit depth :24*

But I am seeing difference in size of images where one having 10.7MB and other 11.7MB. Why this difference?

And how can I make both the images same so I can get correct result. As images are same, so images must be matching.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these images saved to disk, in memory, in a particular file format, raw data?  It could be that the image is the same, but the file format that contains them is different.  Does that mean they are different?

Comment: For info, a 320 x 224 x 3 bytes (24-bit) image should only take up 215,040 bytes.  Not sure where 10.7M is coming from.

Comment: No both the images are in Jpg format

Comment: Then your images dimensions are not even close to correct.  jpg can be a lossy format - the same image can be presented in less space by losing a little information.  If the file is 10M, it is not a 320 x 224 image.  It is much, much bigger.

Comment: @sreevathsabr Obviously if you have to make the images the same size they are not the same. Because jpg is a lossy format, subtle differences in the source images could lead to (large) differences in the final result and the size can be different just after multiple decompress/recompress steps. Size is not how you test if images are the same.

Comment: @NetMage any suggestions wat is the best way to compare so that I can get proper result .. image format doesn't matter to me much (But I want image to be in colour only NOT Black and White)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I don't know wat is going wrong . The data which I have put in the question are seeing the details of the image

Comment: We can't figure out how you need to "make the images same" when you don't provide any information on how they are different, how they are created/retrieved, and for what purposes they need to be the "same".

Comment: @NetMage These images are screen shot taken in different resolution monitor ..I need to check are these screenshot same or the different .. The screenshot contains images and text .

Comment: If the resolutions of the monitors are different, then the screenshots are different, e.g. if a web page is displayed full screen at two different resolutions, the text will be drawn differently, the areas sized differently and the spaces different, scroll bars might disappear, etc.

Comment: @NetMage yes true ,But I had made sure everything is same .Manually I have verified all the contents are same . I agree the point regarding the spaces ..
Is there any way I can compare and get the perfect result?

Comment: If the files are jpg, there should be some native level C# libraries to read them in.  Those libs will report actual size and should give you a buffer that contains the actual RGB data.  Once you have RGB data, you can compare byte for byte.  Or there may already be a method to do this.  5 seconds of googling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413184/converting-a-jpeg-image-to-a-byte-array-com-exception

Comment: "I have written a code in C# which makes images to have same size" We can't possibly see what is wrong unless you actually _put that code in your question_.